# How to load UITreeView in collapsed form in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm using UITreeView by Varun Naharia in my iOS app. How can I load UITreeView in collapsed form first time app starts?

Answer (score 0):

Hook the height constraint as IBOutlet and change it's constant to zero

```
 -(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
 {
    if(once)
    {
        once = NO;

        self.treeViewHCon.constant = 0 ;

        [self.view layoutIfNeeded ];

    }

  }
```

also set

```
   self.treeView.clipsToBounds = YES;
```